# ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and Flash Navigation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

We are working on a website which is small but it use Flash Navigation, as we are using flash so we hard coded the links inside flash, we have given links as below

for home page

> home/aboutus
>
> home/services

and so on for rest of links, the first click work fine, and the url is http://mysite.com/home/aboutus but if we click on services link its making url as http://mysite.com/home/home/aboutus

adding extra home to it, and it also don't work for home page

thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the base url to the Flash movie as parameter so that it can construct proper links:

```
<param name="rootUrl" value="@Url.Content("~/")" />
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but sometime the value in flash is showing undefind

Answer (score 0):

One fun difference in browsers is that the flash player sees the location of the "base" differently. For example, in older versions of IE, relative paths were followed from the location of the page containing the swf, while in FF and other browsers, they were followed from the location of the actual swf. To your embed code, you'll want to add a base param to make all the browsers the same.

```
<param name="base" value=".">
```

You can then pass relative paths based on the location of the swf. Or, you can also adjust the value of the parameter as necessary.